# How to add Checkboxes in Django Form.

Tags: database, django-forms, django-1.9

I want to add checkboxes in my Django form for different NGOs(say NGO1, NGO2, and so on...). I want the user to select those checkboxes and that data should be saved in the database.

Please, Suggest me the necessary changes in the code. I'm using Django 1.9.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

    user=models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.user.first_name
            return self.user.last_name
            return self.user.email
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from volunteer.models import UserProfileInfo

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta():
    model = User
    fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','username')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from volunteer.forms import UserForm



def register(request):

registered = False

if request.method =="POST" :
    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid():

        user = user_form.save()
        user.save()

        registered = True

    else:
        print(user_form.errors)

else:
    user_form = UserForm()

return render(request, 'volunteer/volunteer.html',
                         {'user_form':user_form,
                          'registered':registered})
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from volunteer.models import UserProfileInfo

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(UserProfileInfo)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'volunteer'

urlpatterns = [

 url(r'^', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

volunteer.html(which has the form)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">


<meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


</head>      

<body>   

 <div class="jumbotron">
    {% if registered %}
       <p>Thank you  <p>

    {% else %}
      <h1>Register yourself for Volunteering</h1>




 <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
 <input type="submit" name="" value="Register as a Volunteer">

 {% endif %}

 </div> 


 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

NOTE - I haven't included bootstrap, ajax and JQuery libraries in the above html code due to the formatting issues, I think it has nothing to do with the problem, so.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve that using [checkbox widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple) in django forms.

Define your form class as :

```
NGO_CHOICES = (
('one', 'ONE'),
('two', 'TWO'),
('three', 'THREE'),)

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ngo = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                      choices=NGO_CHOICES)

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('ngo', 'email','first_name','last_name','username')
```

Now while saving the data, you can access the data of checkbox in

```
if request.method =="POST" :
    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid():
        # getting the list of ngos
        ngo = user_form.cleaned_data['ngo']
        user = user_form.save()
        user.save()

        registered = True

    else:
        print(user_form.errors)

else:
    user_form = UserForm()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I can see the checkboxes in my form, but I didn't get how to access the data of checkbox. I can't see that data in admin. Where can I find `user_form.cleaned_data['ngo']`? or should I add that somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for responding, but still I'm not able to understand where I can actually see the checkbox data selected by the user. I modified my views.py as you said. Where can I actually see the checkbox data selected by the user? Will it get automatically loaded in any file? because I can't see that in admin. Sorry for my inability to grasp the solution.

Comment: You said that user will select checkboxes and accordingly data will be saved to db.So it is up to you to implement the logic. You can either define a ngo field in UserProfileInfo or do some custom action based on checkbox selected.